# RPC authenthification explained with windows api

Tags: windows, winapi, rpc

I would like to make a IPC between two processes using Windows RPC. Please explain me like I am five how my application should achieve good security. I want to use `ncalrpc` protocol (processes on the same computer). More exactly:

1. How my client application knows that the server is trusty?
2. How my server know if the callee is the trusted one?

What options do I have? I didn't get `RpcBindingSetAuthInfo` function.

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is not to authenticate on the RPC level, but on the data level, (and as I think, do not use RPC at all, if it is on the same machine use shared memory, else use sockets, it also depends on the realtime level you want to achive) i.e. use public key cryptography, X.509 etc. You can use the InitializeSecurityContext and the rest of the Schannel  functions for that.

Answer (score 0):

For a local connection having the client authenticate the server is fairly hard (for example confirming that some other service did not start in place of the desired program)  but having the server identify the client is not, call RpcBindingInqAuthClient and use the username to determine what action to take, or just use RpcImpersonateClient if you can rely on existing secured objects. Most of the RPC security apparatus is for remote connections rather than ncalrpc.